# Build Debian Package Locally?

Tags: ros, deb, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I was wondering if there was a way to build a ROS debian package locally (for testing purposes). While using Bloom, I have had some trouble in my release. So, before I submit my package again, I'd like to verify that it will build.

thanks,

-Hunter A.

---

I ran the commands you suggested, but encountered an error:

```
allenh1@allenh1-Vostro-430:~/p2os-release$ git checkout debian/ros-hydro-p2os-urdf_1.0.1-0_precise
Note: checking out 'debian/ros-hydro-p2os-urdf_1.0.1-0_precise'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at cd7c4f8... Generated debian files for precise
allenh1@allenh1-Vostro-430:~/p2os-release$ git-buildpackage -uc -us --git-ignore-branch --git-ignore-new
dh  clean
   dh_testdir
Unknown option: buildsystem
dh_testdir: warning: ignored unknown options in DH_OPTIONS
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
Unknown option: buildsystem
dh_clean: warning: ignored unknown options in DH_OPTIONS
    rm -f debian/ros-hydro-p2os-urdf.substvars
    rm -f debian/ros-hydro-p2os-urdf.*.debhelper
    rm -rf debian/ros-hydro-p2os-urdf/
    rm -f debian/*.debhelper.log
    rm -f debian/files
    find .  \( \( -type f -a \
            \( -name '#*#' -o -name '.*~' -o -name '*~' -o -name DEADJOE \
         -o -name '*.orig' -o -name '*.rej' -o -name '*.bak' \
         -o -name '.*.orig' -o -name .*.rej -o -name '.SUMS' \
         -o -name TAGS -o \( -path '*/.deps/*' -a -name '*.P' \) \
        \) -exec rm -f {} \; \) -o \
        \( -type d -a -name autom4te.cache -prune -exec rm -rf {} \; \) \)
    rm -f *-stamp
Warning generated by debuild:
Making debian/rules executable!

fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
gbp:error: release/hydro/p2os_urdf/1.0.1-0 is not a valid branch
```

I'm sure it's something simple.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67345/build-debian-package-locally?/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-22**:
I haven't run into this, I thought this would be covered by the `--git-ignore-branch`, but maybe not...

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-22**:
This seems to indicate that calling this from a tag is a problem, but that hasn't been my experience. I have no idea why this doesn't work, @tfoote any ideas?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-08-06**:
Since bloom uses a tag, not a branch, you might need to use "--git-export=WC" to use the "working copy" that is checked out?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-08-08**:
That seems to make sense. Do I need to change the rest of the command?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-12-14**:
I found that I needed to add the --git-upstream-tree=tag flags to get GBP to run properly on 13.10.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-12-16**:
Austin—just ran into this trying to make builds on 14.04. Thanks for the heads-up.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-07-31**:
Ditto...cheers Austin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can test it locally, but there is no tutorial for doing it yet.

You can checkout the tag in your bloom repo which matches your system, for example:

```
$ git checkout debian/ros-hydro-PACKAGE-NAME_1.0.0-0_precise
```

Then you can build it locally with:

```
$ git-buildpackage -uc -us --git-ignore-branch --git-ignore-new
```

This test should be sufficient for everything but missing dependencies, because this will not build it exactly like the farm, this command will use the packages you have installed locally. So this will not catch errors which happen from missing dependencies, if you have those missing dependencies installed locally.

You can build it just like the farm using `pbuilder`, which builds your package in a vacuum, setting up an empty change root and installing only the packages you depend on. You can do this with this command:

```
$ git-buildpackage -uc -us --git-ignore-branch --git-ignore-new --git-pbuilder
```

This command will do the full, isolated build of your package. Your machine will likely need some setup, it's hard for me to tell what all the steps were as my machines are already setup, but I imagine these should get you close:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-buildpackage pbuilder cowbuilder
$ sudo cowbuilder --create
```

To really mimic the build farm you will want to be using the `ros-shadow-fixed` repository, which is the package repository where packages go to be tested before being synched to the public debian repositories. Comment out any ROS debian entries in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` files and add these lines:

```
deb 'http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu' precise main
deb-src 'http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu' precise main
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-23**:
Now it seems that [tutorial for local pre-release is started](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bloom/Tutorials/LocalPrereleaseTest) under `bloom` tutorial directory.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-09-11**:
For setting `pbuilder` on Ubuntu precise, what you listed worked for me. I only needed [this tweak](http://askubuntu.com/a/372317/24203).

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-11-13**:
I have created a bash script that helps a lot with this task: https://gitlab.com/VictorLamoine/bloom_local_release/tree/master. It makes it easier to handle generating multiple packages when you need to play with rosdep keys so that the dependencies can be resolved.